# How to download image to Xamarin.forms listview

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I have a image url in list view and after click to listview image should download on same row. 
How can I achieve on Xamarin.forms? 
I got image from Azure blob

Comment: Can you add more details such as screenshots or additional information in order to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking this blog post using Xamarin Forms Listview with SQL and Blob storage. They basically used SQL to store the images from Blob storage using the bellow code:

```
public class AzureMediaStorageService : IMediaStorageService
{
    private CloudBlobContainer MediaContainer { get; set; }



    public void InitializeStorage(string settings = null)
    {
        if (MediaContainer != null)
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings), "Azure Storage Media Service needs a connection string name as \"settings\" parameter");

        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[settings].ConnectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        MediaContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("medias");
        MediaContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        MediaContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
    }


    public async Task<Uri> UploadBytesAsync(byte[] bytes, string uniqueId, MediaType mediaType)
    {
        var blockBlob = MediaContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueId);

        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = mediaType == MediaType.Picture ? "image/jpeg" : "video/mp4";

        await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return blockBlob.Uri;
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> DownloadBytesAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }
    }

    public string GetSecureClientUploadUrl(string uniqueId, DateTimeOffset expirationDateTime)
    {
        if (expirationDateTime <= DateTimeOffset.Now)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(expirationDateTime), expirationDateTime, null);

        var blob = MediaContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueId);

        var sasPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = expirationDateTime,
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
        };


        return MediaContainer.Uri + blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy);
    }
}
```

The blog post can be found here:  **https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98784/how-to-load-images-in-xamarin-forms-listview-with-asp-net-web-api-from-sql-azure-database**